# How to extend a Flutter widget and wrap in GestureDetector?

Tags: flutter

I want to extend Flutter's [Dismissible](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Dismissible-class.html) widget and add additional functionality on swipe action.

Flutter favors composition over inheritance so the idea is to wrap the Dismissible widget and add the new functionality in the wrapper widget. In order to handle swipe action I'm trying to wrap the Dismissible in [GestureDetector](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) widget.

However some of the callbacks that I need to handle are not fired (e.g. onHorizontalDragUpdate). I think the problem is that the Dismissible already does handle these events and they are not reaching the wrapper widget.

Do you see any solution to this problem?

Comment: you can check this package available:  https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_slidable

Comment: thank you, I looked at that package but it doesn't have the functionality I'm looking for. I want some animations that are function of the slide position

Comment: I removed my answer. Seems like I saw a bug before instead. But here's how you should do it: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18450

Comment: Thank you for the link to the issue, but unfortunately there is no solution in the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the swipe gesture in [Dismissible](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Dismissible-class.html) by either using `onDismissed` or `confirmDismiss()` and checking the swipe direction.

```dart
Dismissible(
  onDimissed: (direction) {
    if(direction == DismissDirection.startToEnd) {
      // Do something
    }
    if(direction == DismissDirection.endToStart) {
      // Do something
    }
  }
  child: Container(...),
)
```